# CS50 Problem Set 1 (Credit) 2022 Help Needed

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to verify a credit card number by the steps below:

1. Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.
2. Add the sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
3. Check if the last digit of the sum is 0.

Here is my code. I've tried an AMEX card number `371449635398431` but it's giving me `INVALID` so I believe my calculation is incorrect but I've ran over how it would work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
int main(void)
{
    // TODO Prompt for input (DONE)
    long cardnumber;
    do
    {
        cardnumber = get_long("Card no: ");
    }
    while (cardnumber < 0); // Card number must be greater than 0

    // TODO Calculate checksum

    // Get every other digit
    int second = ((cardnumber / 10) % 10);
    int fourth = ((cardnumber / 1000) % 10);
    int sixth = ((cardnumber / 100000) % 10);
    int eighth = ((cardnumber / 10000000) % 10);
    int tenth = ((cardnumber / 1000000000) % 10);
    int twelth = ((cardnumber / 100000000000) % 10);
    int fourteenth = ((cardnumber / 10000000000000) % 10);
    int sixteenth = ((cardnumber / 1000000000000000) % 10);

    // Multiply every other digit by 2 then add those digits
    int checksumpart1 = (second * 2 + fourth * 2 + sixth * 2 + eighth * 2 + tenth * 2 + twelth * 2 + fourteenth * 2 + sixteenth * 2);

    // Get every other other digit
    int first = (cardnumber % 10);
    int third = ((cardnumber / 100) % 10);
    int fifth = ((cardnumber / 10000) % 10);
    int seventh = ((cardnumber / 1000000) % 10);
    int ninth = ((cardnumber / 100000000) % 10);
    int eleventh = ((cardnumber / 10000000000) % 10);
    int thirteenth = ((cardnumber / 1000000000000) % 10);
    int fifteenth = ((cardnumber / 100000000000000) % 10);

    // Sum of every other digit
    int checksumpart2 = (first + third + fifth + seventh + ninth + eleventh + thirteenth + fifteenth);

    // Validity check addition of first two sums
    int checksumfinal = ((checksumpart1 + checksumpart2) % 10);

    // Print AMEX or INVALID

    // validate checksum
    if (checksumfinal != 0) {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    } else {
        printf("VALID\n");
    }
}
```

Ran the program and was provided `INVALID` even though a valid card number of `371449635398431` was used.

I believe my calculations are incorrect but I'm not sure where my error is. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've looked at this repeatedly and cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What platform are you running on?  Because `long` on Windows is 32 bits.

Comment: I'm on Windows 64 bits, could that be causing issues?

Comment: Even for 64-bit Windows, `long` is only 32 bits.  Add `printf( "cardnumber: %ld\n", cardnumber );` after `while (cardnumber < 0);` and before `int second = ((cardnumber / 10) % 10);`.

Comment: Don't use integers to represent credit card numbers. Use a string and process the characters of that as digits. Each digit can be converted to a number by subtracting '0' from its value.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still not quite understanding the number of bits and how this command resolves the issues though.

If you could point me to the general issue so I can read up on the issue a bit more, that would be amazing.

Comment: There are [so many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+credit+card) questions already posted and answered about this. Not sure which one to use as a duplicate, though. :-) A quick look through doesn't give me any with good answers.

Comment: You cannot hold `int` integers with 15 digits precision, as they range from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) is incorrect: the digits at even offsets from the end (counting from 0 for the last digit) should be doubled and if the result is greater than 9, the its digits should be added.

Here is a modified version of your code, using an array to implement the digit conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    // TODO Prompt for input (DONE)
    long cardnumber;
    do {
        cardnumber = get_long("Card no: ");
    }
    while (cardnumber < 0); // Card number must be greater than 0

    // TODO Calculate checksum

    // Get every other digit
    int second      = ((cardnumber / 10) % 10);
    int fourth      = ((cardnumber / 1000) % 10);
    int sixth       = ((cardnumber / 100000) % 10);
    int eighth      = ((cardnumber / 10000000) % 10);
    int tenth       = ((cardnumber / 1000000000) % 10);
    int twelth      = ((cardnumber / 100000000000) % 10);
    int fourteenth  = ((cardnumber / 10000000000000) % 10);
    int sixteenth   = ((cardnumber / 1000000000000000) % 10);

    // Multiply every other digit by 2 then add those digits
    int val[10] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int checksumpart1 = (val[second] + val[fourth] + val[sixth] + val[eighth] +
                         val[tenth] + val[twelth] + val[fourteenth] + val[sixteenth]);

    // Get every other other digit
    int first       = ((cardnumber / 1) % 10);
    int third       = ((cardnumber / 100) % 10);
    int fifth       = ((cardnumber / 10000) % 10);
    int seventh     = ((cardnumber / 1000000) % 10);
    int ninth       = ((cardnumber / 100000000) % 10);
    int eleventh    = ((cardnumber / 10000000000) % 10);
    int thirteenth  = ((cardnumber / 1000000000000) % 10);
    int fifteenth   = ((cardnumber / 100000000000000) % 10);

    // Sum of every other digit
    int checksumpart2 = (first + third + fifth + seventh +
                         ninth + eleventh + thirteenth + fifteenth);

    // Validity check addition of first two sums
    int checksumfinal = (checksumpart1 + checksumpart2) % 10;

    // Print AMEX or INVALID

    // validate checksum
    if (checksumfinal) {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    } else {
        printf("VALID\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a simpler version using a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    long cardnumber;
    do {
        cardnumber = get_long("Card no: ");
    }
    while (cardnumber < 0); // Card number must be greater than 0

    int val[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (long n = cardnumber; n; n /= 100) {
        sum += n % 10 + val[n / 10 % 10];
    }
    // Print AMEX or INVALID
    if (sum % 10)
        printf("INVALID\n");
    else
        printf("VALID\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that depending on the platform, type long may be too small to hold values greater than 2<sup>31</sup> (2147483647) thus unable to represent card numbers as `long` integers.  It would be better to use a string to read the card number and check the digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int luhn_check(const char *str) {
    int val[10] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int sum = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = str[len - i - 1];
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                sum += c - '0';
            else
                sum += val[c - '0'];
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return sum % 10 == 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char *cardnumber = get_string("Card no: ");
    // Print AMEX or INVALID
    if (!luhn_check(cardnumber)) {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    } else {
        printf("VALID\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what "the digits at even offsets from the end should be doubled if below 5 and doubled + 1 if greater or equal to 5." means?

Specifically, I'm lost on why after those even digits are retrieved, why that value can't be just doubled and summed together and why a certain even digit might need to be "doubled +1" instead of just doubled.

If this is related to the long int issue you mentioned at "type long may be too small to hold values greater than 231 (2147483647) thus unable to represent card numbers as long integers," I apologize, I'm still trying to read more on that.

Comment: @DKXP: the definition of the Luhn algorithm is clear: every other digit is doubled and if the result is greater than 9, the digits are summed, which I implement with a table: 0 -> 0, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 5, 8 -> 7, 9 -> 9

Comment: Solved, thank you so much! You were absolutely correct, I misread "add those products’ digits together." for add the doubled integer together i.e. 12 was added instead of 1 + 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here (at least):

```
    // Multiply every other digit by 2 then add those digits
    int checksumpart1 = (second * 2 + fourth * 2 + sixth * 2 + eighth * 2 + tenth * 2 + twelth * 2 + fourteenth * 2 + sixteenth * 2);
```

you have to multiply each digit by 2, and if it is larger than 10, you have to add one to the result.  When you add all the numbers together, you lose which numbers resulted in a number greater than, or equal to 10, so all those increments are lost (every digit in the result not in the units place is lost in the final remainde operation, but you need to consider the ones resulting from duplicating the digits)

NOTE: You don't need to convert the numbers to `int` integers to then separate the digits from the number.  You can convert the individual digits from the string you receive as input (despite the type `int` has no enough capacity to hold a 20 digit card number, neither a `long` or `unsigned long`) but there's an automathon to parse the numbers in string form (processing the digits as they appear in the string)

The code below will compute the correctness of the luhn digits of a string of digits by using a finite automaton that maintains the remainder of the luhn algorithm as the automaton state, and imposes no limit to the input string (you can handle over 20 digit card number without problem):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const static char luhn_tab[][10] = {

    /* state 0, accepting state */
    { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 },
    { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10 },
    { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12 },
    { 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13 },
    { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 },
    { 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
    { 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 },
    { 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 },
    { 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 },

    /* state 10, accepting state */
    {  0,  2,  4,  6,  8,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9 },
    {  1,  3,  5,  7,  9,  2,  4,  6,  8,  0 },
    {  2,  4,  6,  8,  0,  3,  5,  7,  9,  1 },
    {  3,  5,  7,  9,  1,  4,  6,  8,  0,  2 },
    {  4,  6,  8,  0,  2,  5,  7,  9,  1,  3 },
    {  5,  7,  9,  1,  3,  6,  8,  0,  2,  4 },
    {  6,  8,  0,  2,  4,  7,  9,  1,  3,  5 },
    {  7,  9,  1,  3,  5,  8,  0,  2,  4,  6 },
    {  8,  0,  2,  4,  6,  9,  1,  3,  5,  7 },
    {  9,  1,  3,  5,  7,  0,  2,  4,  6,  8 },
};

const static int accepting = (1 << 0) | (1 << 10);

int luhn_ok(char *s, size_t s_len)
{
    s += s_len; /* point to the string end */
    char st = 0; /* automaton state, initially zero */
    while (s_len--) {
        if (isdigit(*--s)) {
            /* operate only on digits, skipping nondigits */
            st = luhn_tab[st][*s - '0'];
        }
    }
    return ((1 << st) & accepting) != 0;
} /* luhn_ok */
```

The algorithm requires you to scan the string from the right side.  If for some reason you cannot do that, and you need to parse it from the left, then you can use the full implementation I've published in [GitHub](https://github.com/mojadita/luhn).  Feel free to use it, as it is opensource.